# OS X launchd.plist

Tags: macos, plist, launchd

Here's my plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.homebrew.autoupdate</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/brew_up</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>86400</integer>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/log/brew.log</string>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/log/brew.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`/usr/local/bin/brew_up` is just a script which calls `brew update`, `brew upgrade` etc

```
#!/bin/sh
echo `date`: Start updating brew
/usr/local/bin/brew update && /usr/local/bin/brew upgrade && /usr/local/bin/brew cleanup
echo `date`: Finish updating brew
```

Then I loaded that file by `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.autoupdate.plist`

Then I tried `launchctl start com.homebrew.autoupdate`, it also worked fine.

But the thing is, it won't start every 24 hours, as I'd expected. Actually now over 48 hours has passed, it's still not started even once. What am I missing here?

Then I changed `StartInterval` to `StartCalendarInterval`

```
  <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>21</integer>
  </dict>
```

Then it was started indefinitely, here's the log file:

```
Thu Aug 7 21:17:20 CST 2014: Finish updating brew
Thu Aug 7 21:17:20 CST 2014: Start updating brew
Already up-to-date.
Thu Aug 7 21:18:14 CST 2014: Finish updating brew
Thu Aug 7 21:18:14 CST 2014: Start updating brew
Already up-to-date.
Thu Aug 7 21:19:39 CST 2014: Finish updating brew
Thu Aug 7 21:19:39 CST 2014: Start updating brew
Already up-to-date.
Thu Aug 7 21:22:28 CST 2014: Finish updating brew
Thu Aug 7 21:22:28 CST 2014: Start updating brew
Already up-to-date.
Thu Aug 7 21:24:46 CST 2014: Finish updating brew
```

Update: I think that means `* 21 * * *` as in crontab, so if it was

```
      <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
      <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>21</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
      </dict>
```

it should work.

But still, what's wrong with `StartInterval`?

BTW, I just tried to write a simple demo to test `StartInterval`, and it totally worked!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.test.touch</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>touch</string>
    <string>/tmp/touched.txt</string>
  </array>
  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>60</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Like you, I've observed that everything works fine when a smaller StartInterval is used: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412388/launchd-plist-with-large-startinterval-never-runs

Answer (score 0):

For *Scheduled Timed Jobs*, you should use the key `StartCalendarInterval` ([Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/ScheduledJobs.html))

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>11</integer>
</dict>
```

Comment: I want it to run every 24 hours, so I think `StartInterval` is more appropriate. From `man launchd.plist`, `StartInterval <integer>
     This optional key causes the job to be started every N seconds.  If the system is asleep, the job will be started the next time the computer wakes up.
     If multiple intervals transpire before the computer is woken, those events will be coalesced into one event upon wake from sleep.`

Comment: @DeanWinchester I have updated my answer with the values necessary for *once a day*. There is also a discussion here about the use of `OnDemand`: https://discussions.apple.com/message/13091303#13091303

Comment: I think that means to start the job at 1st every month, just like how `crontab` works. Are you sure?

Comment: @DeanWinchester Yeah it's similar to `crontab` with missing keys being  wildcarded.  I haven't actually tried it; so I've tried Hour = 11 as I think you are right about the 1st of the month.

Comment: Yeah I guess that'll work. But I'm still trying to figure out how mine wouldn't

Comment: Well there seems to be some confusion about `StartInterval` and using `StartCalendarInterval` is documented as the key to use for cron-like behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There is a note buried somewhere in the `launchd` developer documentation that cautions that on-demand services need to stay around for some minimum amount of time. (Something like 10 seconds IIRC.) Otherwise, `launched` will think they failed to launch properly and will try to restart them.

Try adding a `sleep 30` to your shell script, and see if that fixes the problem of it continually being restarted.

Comment: I think I know what went wrong. <key>Hour</key><integer>21</integer> means * 21 * * * as in crontab, actually it's supposed to be 0 21 * * *, otherwise it'll keeping running until it reaches 22:00. But still can't figure out what's wrong with StartInterval